# How do I return an int based on which radio button is selected?

Tags: android, android-toast, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

radioClick() is returning a value of 1 for the correct answer when I leave the Toast.makeText method in there. I don't want Toast to appear, so I tried removing the method, but now radioClick() will not return a value of 1. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package com.example.android.justjava;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

/**
 * This app displays a quiz about Kankakee County
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    createRadioButtons();

}

/**
 * @param numOfExits is the value passed to the exitsCorrect() method
 * @param answerToQuestionOne is the value passed to the schuyler() method
  */

int numOfExits = 0;
String answerToQuestionOne = "";

/**
 * METHODS WHICH RETURN POINTS FOR CORRECT ANSWERS ARE FOUND BELOW
 */

/** QUESTION 1
 * This method is called to return 1 point if Schuyler Avenue is selected
 * @param answerToQuestionOne
 * @return
 */

public int schuyler(String answerToQuestionOne) {
    if ("Schuyler".equals(answerToQuestionOne)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}


/** QUESTION 2
 * This method calculates whether the correct two boxes were checked and returns 1 point if so
 *
 * @param kccGuessed is whether KCC was guessed
 * @param cobbGuessed is whether Cobb Park was guessed
 * @param depotGuessed is whether the Train Depot was guessed
 * @param majesticGuessed is whether Majestic Theatre was guessed
 */
private int gazebo(boolean kccGuessed, boolean cobbGuessed, boolean depotGuessed, boolean majesticGuessed) {

    if (cobbGuessed && depotGuessed && !kccGuessed && !majesticGuessed ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}


/** QUESTION 3
 * This method awards a point if "2" is selected as the number of exits in Kankakee
 */
public int exitsCorrect(int numOfExits) {
    if (numOfExits == 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is the method that should return 1 when the correct radio button is pressed.

```
/** QUESTION 4
 *
 * this method returns 1 point if Maternity BVM is selected
 */


public int radioClick() {
    RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup);
    int idOfSelected = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    if (idOfSelected == 1){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}

/**
 * END RETURN METHODS
 */


/**
 * METHODS THAT ASSIST WITH QUIZ QUESTIONS ARE FOUND BELOW
 */


/** ASSIST QUESTION 3
 * This method is called when the increment button is clicked.
 */
public void increment(View view) {
    if (numOfExits < 5) {
        numOfExits++;
        displayNumOfExits(numOfExits);
    }
}

/** ASSIST QUESTION 3
 * This method is called when the decrement button is clicked.
 */
public void decrement(View view) {
    if (numOfExits > 0) {
        numOfExits--;
        displayNumOfExits(numOfExits);
    }
}


/** CREATE QUESTION 4
 * This method creates the radio button dynamically
 */
public void createRadioButtons() {
    RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup);

    final String[] radio = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.radio_string_array);

    //Create the buttons
    for (int i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
        final String radioString = radio[i];

        RadioButton button = new RadioButton(this);
        button.setText(getString(R.string.radio_selected, radioString));
```

I tried eliminating the following Toast, but it only returns 1 when the line including Toast is present.

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.you_clicked) + radioString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });


        // Add to radio group
        group.addView(button);
    }
}

/**
 * END QUIZ QUESTION ASSISTS
 */



/**
 * This method is called when the submit button is clicked.
 */
public void submitOrder(View view) {

    EditText questionOneAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.question_one_answer);
    answerToQuestionOne = questionOneAnswer.getText().toString();

    CheckBox kccCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.kcc_checkbox);
    boolean kccGuessed = kccCheckBox.isChecked();

    CheckBox cobbCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cobb_checkbox);
    boolean cobbGuessed = cobbCheckBox.isChecked();

    CheckBox depotCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.depot_checkbox);
    boolean depotGuessed = depotCheckBox.isChecked();

    CheckBox majesticCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.majestic_checkbox);
    boolean majesticGuessed = majesticCheckBox.isChecked();

    int gazeboCorrect = gazebo(kccGuessed, cobbGuessed, depotGuessed, majesticGuessed);
    int numExitsCorrect = exitsCorrect(numOfExits);
    int schuylerCorrect = schuyler(answerToQuestionOne);
    int radioCorrect = radioClick();


    String priceMessage = createQuizSummary(gazeboCorrect, numExitsCorrect, schuylerCorrect, radioCorrect);

    TextView orderSummaryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text_view);
    orderSummaryTextView.setText(priceMessage);


    }


/**
 *
 * @param schuylerCorrect is whether or not question 1 was answered correctly
 * @param gazeboGuessed is whether or not question 2 was answered correctly
 * @param exitsGuessed is whether or not question 3 was answered correctly
 * @param radioCorrect is whether or not question 4 was answered correctly
 * @return String
 */

public String createQuizSummary(int schuylerCorrect, int gazeboGuessed, int exitsGuessed, int radioCorrect) {

    int total =  schuylerCorrect + gazeboGuessed + exitsGuessed + radioCorrect;
    String message = "";

    if (total > 3) {

        message = "Congratulations, you got " + total + " correct!";

    } else if  (total > 2) {

        message = "Not bad, you got " + total + " correct!";

    } else if (total > 1) {

        message = "Meh, you did OK...I guess...\nNext time try to get more than " + total
                + " correct!";

    } else if (total > 0) {

        message = "Crap on a crutch! You only got " + total + " right!";

    } else {

        message = "You didn't get any right! What are you, a yellow hammer?!";

    }

    return message;
}

/**
 * This method displays the number of exits on the screen.
 */
private void displayNumOfExits(int number) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exits_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
}

}
```

Comment: so if you remove toast, your `onClick` method is empty. So but obvious it will do nothing? what is your question really?

Comment: I thought that I could remove button.setOnClickListener() and everything contained in it, because my thinking is that radioClick() will return the id of the clicked radio button, and if the first radio button is selected, then the method will return 1.

Comment: if you want to return the `radioClick()` value, call the function inside the `onClick` method. To check the value if it is called or not, use `Log`

Comment: Of course! It works, obviously. Thank you!